# Ubuntu swiches my vga on every reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have nvidia and intel skylane and installed the proprietary drivers. Everything runs ok. However when I reboot my intel graphics card is used after another reboot without doing anything nvidia is used after another reboot intel is used and so on.

This is my x config file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

In the time when I reboot and intel is detected it is empty
if i lock it or edit in grub to disable gpu manager. I enter in login loop and my resolution is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is connected with gpu-manager, still not found a solution for anyone interested, but here is the log file, when intel is selected
:
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-fglrx-was-loaded file
Looking for fglrx modules in /lib/modules/4.4.0-43-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.4.0-43-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia module: nvidia_361.ko
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? yes
Is fglrx loaded? no
Was fglrx unloaded? no
Is fglrx blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is fglrx kernel module available? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:1916
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915_bpo"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915_bpo"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915_bpo"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915_bpo"
output 0:
    card0-eDP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
The number of cards has changed!
Has the system changed? Yes
main_arch_path x86_64-linux-gnu, other_arch_path i386-linux-gnu
Current alternative: /usr/lib/nvidia-361/ld.so.conf
Current core alternative: (null)
Current egl alternative: /usr/lib/nvidia-361/ld.so.conf
Is nvidia enabled? yes
Is nvidia egl enabled? yes
Is fglrx enabled? no
Is mesa enabled? no
Is mesa egl enabled? no
Is pxpress enabled? no
Is prime enabled? no
Is prime egl enabled? no
Is nvidia available? yes
Is nvidia egl available? no
Is fglrx available? no
Is fglrx-core available? no
Is mesa available? yes
Is mesa egl available? yes
Is pxpress available? no
Is prime available? yes
Is prime egl available? no
System configuration has changed
Single card detected
Selecting mesa
/usr/bin/update-alternatives --set x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
update-alternatives status 0
Calling ldconfig
ldconfig status 0
/usr/bin/update-alternatives --set i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
update-alternatives status 0
Calling ldconfig
ldconfig status 0
/usr/bin/update-alternatives --set x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/ld.so.conf
update-alternatives status 0
Calling ldconfig
ldconfig status 0
Error: no alternative found for unblacklist
Removing xorg.conf. Path: /etc/X11/xorg.conf
System configuration has changed

I see that nvidia is swiched to black list and it removes my xorg.config file

which is diffrent from the time when i reboot and nvidia is automatically selected